# Confusion in max drain current and on-state drain current of 2N7000 E-MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

Below is the datasheet of 2n7000 series of N-channel E-MOSFET. As you can see on the marked box:

Max-Drain Current(continuous) :200mA

On-state Drain Current: 600mA (typical)

Why is the max rating less than the On-state Drain Current? [image]

[image]

Comment: Link to your datasheet? Here's [mine](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N7000-D.PDF) and [another of mine](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/2N7002-8405.pdf) and yet [another](https://neurophysics.ucsd.edu/courses/physics_120/2N7000_Nchannel_MOSFET.pdf).

Comment: It is on a book: Albert Malvino's "Electronic Principle"

Comment: Your second and third link also says the same thing: typical On-state Drain Current is 600mA while max current is:200mA(cont) or 500mA(pulsed). The max rating is greater than on state drain current when Vgs is 4.5V.

Comment: Wait.., it's the other way around: the On-state is greater than max rating which seems wrong to me

Comment: For example, in my 3rd link I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SJ47.png). You may have a good question.

Comment: Taken at face value, it seems that their on-state drain current test sometimes causes the current to exceed the device rating, but they still run it in order to measure the minimum value which is important to specify? Quite odd though

Comment: it makes sense to me that the max no-matter-what (eg. high vds, low vgs) is going to be less than the max under ideal conductive circumstances; high vgs. The absolute max rating isn't the best it can do, it's the worst it can still do reliably.

Comment: Something else doesn't add up here; without heat sinking (not particularly easy for a TO92), even the typical rating of 75mA at 10V Vds (so 750mW) would give a junction temperature rise of over 234C (see thermal information).

Comment: @Peter Smith, yes you're right. And even if we use the minimum on-state current of 75 mA(not the 600mA), the power is 750mW which is **350mW over** the max power dissipation of only 400mW. I wonder where I'm getting wrong here...

Comment: But all this current was measured using note 1. "Pulse Test: Pulse Width < 300μs, Duty Cycle < 2.0%". And this is why Id >> ID_max.

Comment: Yes, but the max drain current rating for "pulsed" is 500mA. Still less than on state current of 600mA.